# Passing variables between Storyboards without Segues - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I'm passing data between two different UIViewControllers located within two different .storyboard files within Xcode. (It's quite a large project so I had to break it up into different storyboards.)

I have already established an "exercisePassed" variable (String) within the view I would like to Pass my data to, and I already know how to move between two views located within different storyboards. Like so.

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "IDEInterface", bundle: nil)
var controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("IDENavController") as! UIViewController

//**************************************
var ex = //Stuck Here
ex.exercisedPassed = "Ex1"
//**************************************

self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

How can I pass the data without using a Segue/PrepareForSegue?

Comment: if it is just a string use nsuserdefaults

Comment: or use setter method to set a variable

Comment: Here's an outstanding explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers

Comment: Don't use nsuserdefaults.  Do it the right way.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'm assuming that the viewController that you want to pass the data to is a custom viewController. In that case, use this amended code here:

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "IDEInterface", bundle: nil)
var controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("IDENavController") as! MyCustomViewController

controller.exercisedPassed = "Ex1"

self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: My view actually has an imbedded UINavigationController. Xcode just gave me the following error **Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x2cdff8c) to 'myApp.myCustomViewController' (0x1d3e18).** any advice? Thanks btw.

Comment: Yes, try changing MyCustomViewController to UINavigationController

Comment: I don't suppose you know how to similarly pass a variable between a .xib popover, and the screen it's currently displayed upon? Having some difficulties with it. Essentially - I want to pass a String from the popover, back to its parent screen. Do I need to reload the parent screen in some way?

Comment: How to do this in Swift 3 ?

Answer (score 3):

your question is not very clear, as far as i have understood

```
//1
//create a variable in "IDENavController"
//e.g 
var someVariable = @""

//2
var controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("IDENavController") as!       UIViewController
controller.someVariable = [assign your variable]

//3
self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. This worked for me.

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "IDEInterface", bundle: nil)
var controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("IDENavController") as! YourDestinationViewControllername
// Add your destination view controller name and Identifier

// For example consider that there is an variable xyz in your destination View Controller and you are passing "ABC" values from current viewController.

controller.xyz = "ABC"

self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Even i have tried similar nature of stuff...it works

Comment: how to do this in swift 3 ?

Answer (score 1):

For those who are looking for the Swift 3/4 answer:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "IDEInterface", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IDENavController") as! CustomViewController

controller.yourVariable = "abc"

self.present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Has been a bit late now. But thanks. I just upvoted.

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help :)