# How do I transfer variables between two storyboards in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am currently programming an app with two storyboards. One storyboard is an onboarding storyboard where I obtain crucial info from the user in order to run the app. Another is the main app. How can I create  variable that is able to be manipulated and accessible to both storyboards? I am using Swift.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have code that you have tried and didn't work as you expected?  If so include that in your question.

Comment: No I don't really know where to start so I don't have anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to go back and fourth between using ***UserDefaults*** and sending data via ***prepareForSegue***

UserDefaults Guide : [Setting And Getting Data With UserDefaults In Swift](https://learnappmaking.com/userdefaults-swift-setting-getting-data-how-to/)

prepareForSegue sample : [stackoverflow prepareForSegue sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24040979/5314632)

With prepareForSegue, create empty variables in your destination ViewController that will receive data, then set them in the prepareForSegue function in your origin view controller.

Example

```
class DestinationViewController: UIViewController{
      var value1: String!
      var value2: Int!
}


//SWIFT 4
class OriginViewContoller: UIViewContoller{
      override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
          switch(segue.identifier){
             case "SEGUE_IDENTIFIER_HERE":
                 let vc = segue.destination as! DestinationViewController
                 vc.value1 = "Some String"
                 vc.value2 = 1234
          }
      }
}
```

If I am using UserDefaults to keep track of important user data, I make sure to remove this data from UserDefaults when the user logs out

Example

```
UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "SOME_KEY_IDENTIFIER_HERE")
```

Comment: Thank you! I used UserDefaults actually and it worked quite well. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051629/passing-variables-between-storyboards-without-segues-swift) here in Stackoverflow

```
var storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "IDEInterface", bundle: nil)
var controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("IDENavController") as! MyCustomViewController

controller.exercisedPassed = "Ex1"

self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```